# How to properly check a date range for my case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

Given the following data:

```
{u'Type1': ((6, 1), (9, 30)),
 u'Type2': ((1, 10), (5, 31)),
 u'Type3': ((9, 1), (1, 9))}
```

I want to assign a type to a date. In this data structure the first pair, e.g. `(6, 1)` refers to `(start month, start day)`, while the second pair refers to `(end month, end day)`. Thus, I have date ranges.

I have a problem with assigning a type to the date `2015-01-06`. It should be `Type3`, however due to year change my code does not work for this particular case. How can I adjust it?

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

text = '''[{"end-day":31,"end-month":5,"type":"Type2","start-day":10,"start-month":1},{"end-day":9,"end-month":1,"type":"Type3","start-day":1,"start-month":9},{"end-day":30,"end-month":9,"type":"Type1","start-day":1,"start-month":6}]'''

json_types = json.loads(text)
dt = datetime.strptime("2015-01-06 11:00:00.0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")


def getType(dt,json_types):

    types = {k['type']: ((k['start-month'],k['start-day']),(k['end-month'],k['end-day'])) for k in json_types}

    tt = "NA"    
    for t, (start, end) in types.items():
        if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):
            tt = t
            break
        if tt != "NA":
            break
    return tt
```

Comment: Do you get errors? If so please post the Traceback

Comment: He doesn't get errors with traces, just wrong behavior as described in the text.  The given date is not recognized to be within the new-year-event spanning range.

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError for the comparison between a tuple and a datetime.date object - `(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date()`

Comment: @wwii: Maybe that's because of my imports `from datetime import datetime`, `from datetime import date`?

Comment: Should it be `date.(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date()`?

Comment: Have you tried printing *variables* in your loop to see what is happening?

Comment: @wwii: There should be `if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):` in the code. I somehow deleted the part of this statement. Now the posted code is an exact copy of mine, so it should run without errors.

Comment: Before the comparison, test to see if your end date is is less than your start date; if it is add one year to the end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to plain English,

```
1. 10-01 and 31-05 (Jan to March)
2. 01-09 and 09-01 (September to Jan)
3. 01-06 and 30-09 (June to September)
```

I ran the code, and printed this output:

```
Checking date: 2015-01-06

Start: 2015-01-10
End: 2015-05-31

Start: 2015-09-01
End: 2015-01-09

Start: 2015-06-01
End: 2015-09-30

NA
```

So, what is going wrong, is this `if` condition:

```
if datetime.date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) < dt.date() < datetime.date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):
```

For example, for type 2, your condition looks like this:

```
if 01-09 is less than 06-01 is less than 09-01
```

September 1st is not less (that is, before) 6th January, hence the `if` condition fails.

This is because, you are checking for the dates across two different years. If your start month is after the end month in the calendar (September is after January), then these should be of two different years.

```
01-09-2015 and 09-01-2016 (September to Jan) would make more sense
```

Or, as the OP solved his own issue in the comments, subtract a year instead of adding:

```
for t, (start, end) in types.items():
    start_year = dt.year
    end_year = dt.year

    if (start[0] > end[0]):
        start_year = dt.year-1

    start_d = datetime.date(start_year,start[0],start[1])
    end_d = datetime.date(end_year,end[0],end[1])

    print("between: " + str(start_d) + " and " + str(end_d))
    if start_d < dt.date() < end_d:
        tt = t
        break
```

Comment: Yes, that's the case. The question is how to check the date range given my input data? The problem exists when there is a year's change.

Comment: Oh, I cannot flip dates, because there will be overlapping with other date ranges. The whole thing is in the year's change.

Comment: I mean, check the months and make the start as end and end as start, if the start month is more than the end month.

Comment: Yes, but this `01-09-2015 and 09-01-2015` overlaps with `2015-01-10 and 2015-05-31`. So, swapping does not work here (if I properly understood your solution).

Comment: I added this `start_year = dt.year   end_year = dt.year    if (start[0] > end[0]):
end_year = dt.year+1`, but still the same problem.

Comment: The print outputs this result for the for loop (it's correct, but I still get NA): `2015-01-10 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-05-31
2015-09-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2016-01-09
2015-06-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-09-30`

Comment: The way your data is, if you add a year to the whole year change issue we are facing and make it 2016 Jan, your date is still in 2015 Jan and won't be shown as Type2. If I don't add a year, and decide to keep it 2015, your date still wont be shown as Type 2, because the start date will be Jan 9th. You are missing out on the time period from September to Jan by avoiding year change. So, the coding part is correct.

Comment: Or maybe just use `start_year = dt.year
        end_year = dt.year
        if (start[0] > end[0]):
            start_year = dt.year-1`. It works fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can just make it to the previous year. Good catch. I didn't think of it that way. I'm at my office; the 10-hour shift has got to my head.

Answer (score 1):

Printing variables, predicates, evaluations, and other relevant objects can give you insight into what your code is doing.

Adding a few lines can show you what your comparison is doing

```
...
    for t, (start, end) in types.items():
        before = datetime.date(dt.year,start[0],start[1])
        test = dt.date()
        after = datetime.date(dt.year,end[0],end[1])
        print('{} <= {} <= {} --> {}'.format(before, test, after, before <= test <= after))
    ...


>>> getType(dt=dt,json_types=json_types)
2015-01-10 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-05-31 --> False
2015-09-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-01-09 --> False
2015-06-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-09-30 --> False
'NA'
```

It appears that the value you are testing is not between any of the limits for your types.

Even if you try to account for a year change in a type's time span, the comparison still fails ...

```
    for t, (start, end) in types.items():
        before = datetime.date(dt.year,start[0],start[1])
        test = dt.date()
        after = datetime.date(dt.year,end[0],end[1])
        print('{} <= {} <= {} --> {}'.format(before, test, after, before <= test <= after))
        if after < before:
            after += datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
            print('\t{} <= {} <= {} --> {}'.format(before, test, after, before <= test <= after))

        if before <= test <= after:
            ...

>>> getType(dt=dt,json_types=json_types)
2015-01-10 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-05-31 --> False
2015-09-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-01-09 --> False
    2015-09-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2016-01-09 --> False
2015-06-01 <= 2015-01-06 <= 2015-09-30 --> False
'NA'
```